# Using binomial distribution in hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I stumbled along this question, however I haven't found any solutions, the question is:

"A social media app was rated 'excellent' by 70% of its users based upon a large sample. They wondered if the percentage of users rating the app as 'excellent has changed' A random sample of 28 customers were asked to rate the app and 15 rated it as 'excellent'

Use binomial distribution to investigate at 5% significance level whether there is evidence to support the claim that the percentage of users who rate the app as 'excellent' has changed."

What I have done:

I let x be the R.V. denoting the number of excellent ratings so

$$X \sim\ B(N,P) $$ where n = 28 and p = 0.7

My expected value is $ E(X) = np = 28$ x $0.7 = 19.6 $ but we have $15$ rating it as excellent.

Next I created a null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis which is,

$$H_0 : p = 0.7$$
$$H_1 : p > 0.7$$

where p is the proportion of people who voted excellent.

Assuming the previous is correct I am trying to solve this,

$$P(X \geq 15) = 1 - P(X\leq 14)$$

However, I'm not sure if this is correct or how I solve this using binomial since $n = 28$ isn't in my binomial table. Also the question asks whether "percentage of users rating the app as 'excellent has changed" does this mean my alternative hypothesis should be

$$H_1 : p \neq 0.7$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative hypothesis should be $p\neq 0.7$, cause the number of users who rate "excellent" could both grow and decrease, and the problem asks for "changed".

You should compute the threshold values of the binomial distribution $Bin(28,0.7)$ such that the total weight of the upper and lower tails of the distribution (that is, parts of the distribution lying out of threshold values) is $5\%$, and check if the number $15$ is lying within the threshold values or not; if not, you reject null hypothesis at significance level $5\%$.

---

PS: Using R, the thresholds are

```
> qbinom(0.025,28,0.7)
[1] 15
> qbinom(0.975,28,0.7)
[1] 24
>
```

$15$ is still within the thresholds, so we fail to reject.

---

PPS: p-value of observing $15$ is

```
> pbinom(15, 28, 0.7)+1-pbinom(24,28,0.7)
[1] 0.06475742
```

which also shows that we fail to reject at significance level $5\%$

Comment: Thanks for the help, with regards to checking the threshold normally I would look at my table search for n and then the x value and check if it lies within the 5% significance so I can reject or accept the null, however using the tables I only have n = 25 then it goes to n = 30, since n = 28 its throwing me off a bit.

Comment: People forgot tables long before and use R or Python. You need 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of binomial distribution, should be `qbinom` function in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using the $\bf{p}$-value of your test statistic $x = 15$.

Since the test asks only about a possible change of the proportion $p = 0.7$, you have $H_1: p\neq 0.7$.

So, this is a two-tailed test based on the distribution $X\sim B(28,0.7)$.

The $\bf{p}$-value for $x=15$ is the probability - under the assumption that $p=0.7$ - of getting a result with the same or even larger absolute deviation from the expected mean $E(X) = np=19.6 \Rightarrow 19.6-15 = 4.6$:

$${\bf{p}} = P(|X-np|\geq 4.6\,|\, H_0)$$

If ${\bf{p}}\leq 5\%$ (the significance level), $H_0$ is rejected.

Using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://P(%7CX-19.6%7C%3E=4.6),%20X~B(28,0.7)) you get

$${\bf{p}} \approx 0.065 > 5\% \Rightarrow H_0 \text{ is not rejected }$$

Comment: @JB191 : This is the $\bf{p}$-value for the absolute deviation from the mean in both directions symetrically about the mean. Have you checked my link and scrolled down to the plot? There you can "see" why it is $5\%$.